# What does Bhakti do in ones life?

Tags: vishnu, dharma, bhakti

Vedas say God gives the side of Dharma and Dharma says only when we complete our cycle of karma (papa and Punya) we can attain him, then what is the use of Bhakti?

> Om Apavitrah Pavitro Vaa Sarva-Avasthaam Gato-[A]pi Vaa |
> Yah Smaret-Punnddariikaakssam Sa Baahya-Abhyantarah Shucih ||

This Sanskrit mantra says one who thinks of Pundarikaksha becomes pure, If one becomes pure doesn't that mean one is free from papa and why doesn't one attain Mukti by chanting the mantra (I mean instantly attaining God)

1)Is Bhakti just a way to praise him? I have read that one eye of Vishnu is the sun and the other is the moon which means he follows Dharma strictly and only then gives Mukti whereas the other eye is for his kindness,

2)Can Bhakti reduce our karma

3)does Bhakti only help us attain Mukti or does it help us in our materialistic desires too?

A good explanation is appreciated

Comment: Your question is broad, please try to narrow down for good answers.

Comment: Sakam bhakts have many exmapole , say druva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This sanskrit mantra says one who thinks of Pundarikaksha becomes pure

Yes, as in the story of Ajāmiḷa who attained mukti on his deathbed after a life of vice by unknowingly chanting 'Nārāyaṇā'.

In the Bhagavadgīta, Bhagavān says

> antakālē ca mām ēva smaraṇ muktvā kalēvaram 
> yah prayāti saḥ mad bhāvam yāti nāsti atra samśayaḥ.
>
> And whoever, at the time of death, quits his body, remembering Me alone, at > once attains My nature. Of this there is no doubt. (BG 8:5, trans. Śrīla Prabhupāda)

> Can Bhakti really reduce our karma

Yes, greatly. See [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37258/is-there-any-statement-that-bhakti-destroys-karma).

> does Bhakti only help us attain mukti or does it help us in our materialistic desires too?

Bhakti does help one gain material contentment. From the Periya Tirumozhi of Tirumangai Azhvar:

> kulam tharum selvam thanthidum adiyaar paduthuyar aayinavellaam nilandaram cheyyum neel vishumbarulum arulodu perunilam alikkum
>
> valam tharum mattrum thanthidum pettra thaayinum aayina cheyyum nalam tharum shollai naan kandukonden 'narayana' ennum naamame
>
> It gives you status, wealth, eliminates sorrow by demolishing them to the ground. It bestows you with lengthy heaven along with lots of land. It blesses you with strength and all sorts of good things. It does more than what a mother would do to a child. And I found that all good bestowing name, Narayana. Here land means not only the materialistic property land, but grounds on which the person is recognised. (From: a [somewhat reputable blog](http://rprabhu.blogspot.com/2007/10/truthful-thirumangai-azhwar.html), the translation seems correct to my limited Tamil)

Comment: When will Bhakti fruit? after 1day 1 week? when?

Comment: Thx this is helpful 